# jQuery - how to resize two div simultaneously?

Tags: jquery, resize

I would like to allow a user to set height of two divs in same time.

Here is the sketch what i try to do:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/23rdtjwq/)

Sum of heights both divs have to be static all the time - i.e.:

```
top=100, bottom=300
top=50, bottom=350
```

User can drag div called "middle" to resize...

Its possible to do with jQuery UI Resizable class, or should i look for another solution?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% clear on what you're trying to achieve but form what I can gather you need the following:

I've removed the ids from the HTML as these need to be unique so were incorrectly used anyway. I've then added two separate classes the top and bottom elements and a resizable-control class to the middle.

```
// Make the middle element resizeable.
var resizableControl = $('.resizable-control').resizable();

// On resize of the middle element...
resizableControl.on('resize', function () {

    // Get the height and width
    var height = $(this).height();
    var width = $(this).width();

    // Resize the top and bottom elements to the middle 
    // element's height + their original height.
    $('.resizable').css({
        'height': height + 100,
        'width': width
    })
});
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/mark_c/23rdtjwq/3/

Comment: That's not what i'm looking for but thanks for your answer.

When someone drag middle div up, top div should be shrink (i.e. -40px height) and bottom div should grown up (+40px height). 

Middle div it's just a bar which can be draggable.